# Missing hits on lucene index search

Tags: java, indexing, full-text-search, lucene

i index one big database overview (just text fields) on which the user must be able to search (below in indexFields method). This search before was done in the database with ILIKE query, but was slow, so now search is done on index. Hovewer, when i compare search results from db query, and results i get with the index search, there is always much less results with search from index. 
Im not sure if i am making mistake in indexing or in search process. To me all seems to make sense here. Any ideas?

Here is the code. All advices appreciated!

```
 // INDEXING
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(
                Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, stopSet); // stop set is empty
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(INDEX_DIR, analyzer, true,
                IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

        indexFields(writer);
        writer.optimize();
        writer.commit();
        writer.close();
        analyzer.close();
```

---

```
private void indexFields(IndexWriter writer) {

    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria
            .forClass(Activit.class);

    int count = 0;
    int max = 50000;
    boolean existMoreToIndex = true;

    List<Activit> result = new ArrayList<Activit>();


    while (existMoreToIndex) {

        try {
            result = activitService.listPaged(count, max);
            if (result.size() < max)
                existMoreToIndex = false;

            if (result.size() == 0)
                return;

            for (Activit ao : result) {
                Document doc = new Document();
                doc.add(new Field("id", String.valueOf(ao.getId()),
                        Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                if(ao.getActivitOwner()!=null)
                    doc.add(new Field("field1", ao.getActivityOwner(),Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                if(ao.getActivitResponsible() != null)
                    doc.add(new Field("field2", ao.getActivityResponsible(), Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));

                try {
                    writer.addDocument(doc);
                } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }
            count += max;
```

---

```
 //SEARCH
    public List<Activit> searchActivitiesInIndex(String searchCriteria) {
    Set<String> stopSet = new HashSet<String>(); // empty because we do not    want to remove stop words
    Version version = Version.LUCENE_CURRENT;
    String[] fields = {
            "field1", "field2"};
    try {
        File tempFile = new File("C://testindex");
        Directory INDEX_DIR = new SimpleFSDirectory(tempFile);
        Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(INDEX_DIR, true);

        QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(version, fields, new StandardAnalyzer(
                version, stopSet));


        Query query = parser.parse(searchCriteria);

        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, 500);

        ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;


        //here i always get smaller hits lenght

        searcher.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Print topDocs.totalHits, if you are not doing it already. That number will give you the total documents matching your query.

Comment: @Shashikant Kore: i am already doing that and see that number is wront, thats why i posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the analyzer is doing something that you aren't expecting.

Open your index using [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/), you can see what your (analyzed) indexed documents look like, as well as your parsed queries - should let you see what's going wrong.

Also, can you give an example of `searchCriteria`? And the corresponding SQL query?  Without that, it's hard to know if the indexing is done correctly. You may also not need to use `MultiFieldQueryParser`, which is quite inefficient.

Comment: I am using MultiFieldQueryParser(i guess you missed it :))! search criteria are just simple strings such as "hotel" "hot" or anything else. I am using MultiFieldQueryParser because i dont want to search on each field separately

Comment: @Julia, that was my point, if you're using MultiFieldQueryParser, you _are_ searching the fields separately, it just provides some syntactic sugar.  If you want your keywords to match in any of the fields, it's much better to combine the text into a single field.